# Is the series $ 1-1+1-1+1+\cdots = -1+1-1+1-1+1-\cdots $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

We have the series

$$ S = 1-1+1-1+1-1+1 \cdots $$

If we manipulate S, we get that
$$ 1 - S = S $$
$$ 1 = 2S $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} = S $$

Also, if we re-order S, we get that

$$ S = (1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)\cdots $$

$$ = -1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1\cdots $$

So $$ -S = S + 1  $$

Solving for S we get that

$$ S = -\frac{1}{2} $$

My question is, is the new S re-ordered considered the same series as S? When we can say that two series are the same in that context? Thanks.

Comment: Very bad idea to *manipulate* divergent series.

Comment: What definition of convergence/divergence are you using?

Comment: Rearrangement of terms of a series is possible only if it converges. The above series doesn't converge, hence you can't rearrange terms to get the same series.

Comment: As for $S=\frac{1}{2}$, certainly not by the usual definition of convergence.  You are alluding to [Cesaro Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).  Having "*re-ordered*" the one series into the other, as you have found, does *not* maintain the cesaro sum.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that even for convergent series in the usual sense, rearrangement can alter the outcome.  See [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: You are only allowed to rearrange the sum, if the sum is absolute convergent, i.e. if the sum of the absolute values of the summands converges.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've done something """"""ilegal"""""", I'm a 15-years-old self student studying calc 1 and the other that I was playing with these series. All the corrections are good.

Comment: @Kaind: rearrangement of a series is only guaranteed to preserve the limit if the series is *absolutely* convergent. Have a look into the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: @alexperez-cst doing algebraic manipulations on infinite algebraic expressions is something that we now know requires great care. There is no law against it, but in the court of mathematics, it is now subject to very rigorous scrutiny. But don't despair: great mathematicians like Euler routinely did this kind of thing and came up with great mathematical results, which later mathematicians confirmed using rigorous (and often much harder) methods.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, this series is not convergent, so there's no such thing as sum of the series $S$.

Even if it was a convergent series, like for example
$$ 1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \dots $$
in general, if you rearrange the terms, it is possible to obtain a different sum. For example, if you rearrange them as follows:
$$ 1 + \frac13 -\frac12 + \frac15 +\frac17-\frac14 + \frac19+\frac{1}{11}-\frac16 + \dots $$
(two positive terms then one negative, repeat) you will get a different sum.

Only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent, that is, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ is convergent, then it is guaranteed that rearranging the terms will not change the sum. So, for example in the series
$$ 1-\frac14 + \frac19-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25} + \dots$$
you can rearrange terms whatever way you want, and the sum will remain the same.

The theorem it states that is called the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: $S$ being given a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ is a thing that is done, frequently enough, that it should be alluded to in any answer to be considered complete so I disagree with completely dismissing it as "no such thing as...$S$."  Just as the sum $1+2+3+4+\dots$ can be assigned a value of $-\frac{1}{12}$.  It isn't meaningless, but it does need to be adequately clarified the context and definitions used that lead to those results.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thanks for the comment supporting my comment on the question. I guess my ultimate MSE question would be "How can I think like Euler did?" - but I guess that would be off-topic.

Comment: @Adam it may not be the *sum* of the series, but it is the "*super-sum*" of the series, or the "*[Cesaro Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)*" of the series, both of which are perfectly reasonable things to talk about and neither of which require talking about analytic continuations.

Comment: $\frac12$ is NOT a sum of this series. It is a value of an analytic continuation at $q=1$ of the function that for $|q|<1$ can be defined as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-q)^{n}$. Calling it a sum of a series is incorrect, and may lead to erronous conclusions.

Comment: I encourage you (*and anyone else reading comments here*) to see [Mathologer's video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuIIjLr6vUA) criticizing and expanding upon and correcting Numberphile's video about the $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac{1}{12}$ factoid.  He goes on to explain the mathematics behind these ideas and justify them.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to get this series will be with the help of Binomial Expansion of $\frac{1}{2}$ as follows

$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+1 }= (1+1)^{-1}$

Expansion will be as follows

$1^{-1} + \frac{(-1)}{1!}(1)^{-2} \cdot(1)^1+\frac{(-1)\cdot(-2)}{2!}1^{-3}\cdot1^2+...  = 1-1+1-1+…$

Clearly now in your question

LHS = $\frac{1}{2} $

RHS = $-1+\frac{1}{2} =  \frac{-1}{2} $

**In this context RHS $\neq$ LHS**

Some more interesting series with Binomial Expansion will be awesome, may be sometimes divergent series also

For example

Expansion of $\frac{1}{3}$ can be done in 2 ways

Conventional and logic way of expansion will be $$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2+1 }= (2+1)^{-1}$$ which will expand into

$$ 2^{-1}+ \frac{-1}{1!}\cdot 2^{-2}+\frac{{(-1)}\cdot{(-2)}}{2!}\cdot2^{-3}+\frac{{(-1)}\cdot{(-2)}\cdot(-3)}{3!}\cdot2^{-4}...$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}+...$$

Another way to put this Binomial Expansion will be $$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{1+2}= (1+2)^{-1}$$

Expansion now will give different result

$$ 1^{-1}+ \frac{-1}{1!}\cdot 1^{-2}\cdot2^1+\frac{{(-1)}\cdot{(-2)}}{2!}\cdot2^{2}+\frac{{(-1)}\cdot{(-2)}\cdot(-3)}{3!}\cdot2^{3}...$$

And this will be $$1-2^1+2^2-2^3+...$$ a divergent series alternating from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$